# VueJS - How to make a list automatically scroll when selected item is out of the view?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Here is an working example that I followed: https://codepen.io/alligatorio/pen/mXRGLg?editors=1010

I want to scroll the list automatically when selecting an item out of the list's view box to make the item visible.
I've tried using `scrollIntoView` on the selected `<li>`, but it only worked OK when scrolling down, and it also scrolled the upper parent (if the upper parent is scrollable).

Could you give me some ideas on how to deal with this?
Thanks a lot!